# How to make pack to fill data with zeroes from the beginning?

Tags: perl, hex, pack

I'm using [`pack / unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) in perl to convert hex values to decimal like this:

```
print unpack "S", reverse pack "H4", "1230";
> 4656
```

Everything is good while data is 4 hex symbols.
If data length is not enough to fit requested format pack adds zeroes to the end.

Like this:

```
print unpack "b*", pack "H4", "FF";
> 1111111100000000
```

It causes:

```
print unpack "S", reverse pack "H4", "123";
> 4656
```

While I'd like it to be the same as [`oct`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/oct.html):

```
print oct("0x123");
> 291

print unpack "S", reverse pack "H4", "0123";
> 291
```

**How to make pack to add zeroes at the beginning of the data when data length not enough to fit format?**

### Short FAQ

**What are you trying to do?**
I have bunch of functions to deal with different types of data (`float`, `short`, `long`, `ushort`, `ulong`, etc). All conversions are done in using `pack`/`unpack`. These functions are needed to convert data produced by third-party.

**Why not to use `oct` or `hex`?**
Because I have to deal with signed integer and float. And I want all functions to be similar for better code understanding.

**Could you provide more examples?** Here they are:

**Example 1:** Signed short integer (full data received). System receives hex data `018F` from third party. This data supposed to be `signed short`, so it is processed in the following way:

```
print unpack "s", reverse pack "H4", "018F";
> 399
```

**Example 2:** Signed short integer (half data received). System receives hex data `8F` from third party. `8F` is only 1 byte, while 2 bytes needed to form short integer. It is processed in the same way:

```
print unpack "s", reverse pack "H4", "8F";
> -28928
```

But third party means `008F` not `8F00`:

```
print unpack "s", reverse pack "H4", "008F";
> 143

print unpack "s", reverse pack "H4", "8F00";
> -28928
```

**What about endianness?**
In all examples received data is `big-endian`, while my system is `little-endian` that is why `reverse` used.

**How do you deal with it now?** I'm using sprintf to add zeroes.

```
print unpack "s", reverse pack "H4", sprintf "%04s", "8F";
> 143
```

**What version of perl do you use?** 5.8.8

Comment: Seems like a [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341) to me. What are you trying to do ?
`printf("%04d",hex("123"))` should suffice otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for pointing `XY Problem`. I have added **Short FAQ** section to my question to provide additional information. Hope now it is more clear.

Answer (score 4):

You know there's a built-in `hex` function for converting hex values to decimal, don't you?

```
$ perl -e 'print hex("123")'
291
```

Comment: `hex` function can be used only for unsigned integers (as far as I know). But I have to deal with signed integer too.

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is just endian-ness, use the `<` and `>` modifiers in your unpack template.
See [`perldoc -f pack`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#pack). The designers of Perl were not ignorant about these issues:

```
print unpack "s", reverse pack "H4", "008F";
> 143        (on little-endian system)

print unpack "s>", pack "H4", "8F";
> 143
```